# Authenticating stomp web socket clients

Tags: authentication, websocket, stomp, torquebox

I have a ruby on rails application deployed to torquebox. I need some way to secure the websockets in my application. I am using the stomp websockets , is there a way to authenticate users while they make a websocket connection? I could use the username and password parameters but they are currently ignored. Is there any other way to authenticate this connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate a message to a Stomplet by using the session and a stored token. For this to work, you have to setup Rails to use the Torquebox session store. This can be done with an initializer, such as `config/initializers/torquebox_init.rb`:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :torquebox_store
```

Now the Stomplet will have access to the session. Here is an example Stomplet that uses the session param `:authentication_token` to match the User's authentication_token in the database. The auth token is checked for subscribing, sending a message, and unsubscribing:

```
require 'torquebox-stomp'

class StompletDemo

  def initialize()
    super
    @subscribers = []
  end

  def configure(stomplet_config)
  end

  def on_message(stomp_message, session)
    token = session[:authentication_token]

    if is_authenticated?( token )
      @subscribers.each do |subscriber|
        subscriber.send( stomp_message )
      end
    end
  end

  def on_subscribe(subscriber)
    session = subscriber.session
    if is_authenticated?(session[:authentication_token])
      @subscribers << subscriber
    end
  end

  def on_unsubscribe(subscriber)
    session = subscriber.session
    if is_authenticated?(session[:authentication_token])
      @subscribers.delete( subscriber )
    end
  end

  def is_authenticated?(token)
    User.where( authentication_token: token ).exists?
  end

end
```

Now all you have to do is make sure that when the user authenticates, the `session[:authentication_token]` is set. Mostly like this will be set in a controller:

```
 # user has successfully authenticates
 session[:authentication_token] = @user.authentication_token
```

Answer (score 1):

For other people having this issue, this is how I solved it.

https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/6207839

Basically the token system didnt scale for me, especially since I use devise.
If you want to host your websocket in say a chrome extension its easier to just pass username/password directly to stomp and have it manage its own virtual subscriber sessions in the stomplet. This also allow you to do some fun things as far as who you are pushing to.